# How to convert a 3D dataset into a 2D dataset on a grid?

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, reshape, flatten

My problem is the following:

I have a 3D dataset where (x,y) are the cartesian coordinates of a grid and (z) is the intensity/frequency of each point in the grid, named (f).

I want to convert this 3D dataset (x,y,f) into a 2D (x,y) dataset, where I'll create new data points in the (x,y) grid according to the intensity of the signal.

For example, I have the following graph and dataset:
This is some form of a "heat map" where the coordinate (z) is the intensity of the signal

[image]

I want to convert this 3D dataset into a 2D one where new data points will be created according to the intensity of a previous data point. For example, if the intensity for (x=1, y=1) is 20, I want to create 20 data points at (x=1,y=1) with intensity 1.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
# make (small) example
f = np.random.randint(1,4,(2,3))
yxf = np.c_[(*map(np.ravel,(*np.indices(f.shape),f)),)]
yxf
# array([[0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 3],
#        [0, 2, 3],
#        [1, 0, 2],
#        [1, 1, 2],
#        [1, 2, 2]])

# process 
yxf[:,:2].repeat(yxf[:,2],axis=0)
# array([[0, 0],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 2],
#        [0, 2],
#        [0, 2],
#        [1, 0],
#        [1, 0],
#        [1, 1],
#        [1, 1],
#        [1, 2],
#        [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the scikit module installed, then you can use the rgb2grey (or rgb2gray) to make a photo from color to gray (from 3D to 2D)

```
from skimage import io, color

lina_color = io.imread(path+img)
lina_gray = color.rgb2gray(lina_color)

In [33]: lina_color.shape
Out[33]: (1920, 1280, 3)

In [34]: lina_gray.shape
Out[34]: (1920, 1280)
```